# How powerful is Drupal really?

Tags: drupal

I've been using Drupal for a long time, and know that it's robust and has tons of features. My question is, is it a framework that you can build REALLY big sites on? And can anyone give some examples of REALLY big sites that have been built with Drupal?

To answer my question about whether or not it's a good idea to build really big sites on Drupal, imagine having to redo facebook as a drupal site. Would it be possible (realistically)?

Comment: Facebook has a lot of very unique scaling problems. Quantcast ranks it as number 3 on the web (after google and yahoo). You really shouldn’t be planning for that type of scaling problem just yet (One of the recent stack overflow podcasts talks about this.) However if you are interested in this type of scaling problem there is a Blog on Facebook Engineering which is fascinating http://www.facebook.com/notes.php?id=9445547199

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> imagine having to redo facebook as a drupal site. Would it be possible (realistically)?

Yes but I wouldn't. You should probably define "Big." Do you mean big as in tons of pages or DB storage? Do you mean big as in amount of visitors? Do you mean big as in famous? Drupal is a fine CMS and if scaled properly I'm sure you can handle a large load of visitors. But the main point here is that it is a CMS (with extensibility) and not a good framework for making something completely custom. If you need something truly unique then you should use a real framework like CakePHP or CodeIgnitor, etc.

Comment: By big I meant: handle a LOT of users and stores a lot of information on those users (which is why I mentioned facebook). Off topic, but if you don't know CakePHP, would you recommend learning it, or sticking to Drupal?

Comment: Depends entirely on your needs. You might be a little overoptimistic if you're thinking you'll be making the next Facebook, though. :-p

Comment: I'm biased here and would tell you to learn CakePHP anyway but if I tried to get rid of my bias I would say it depends on how unique the functionality of the site is. If you need a CMS, Blog, Shopping cart or other things that Drupal does easily then stick with Drupal. If you have more unique requirements then CakePHP would probably be better. The learning curve with Cake is pretty easy.

Comment: I'd agree with Kyle - if it's a fairly unique use case, custom code with a framework like Cake or CodeIgniter is probably the way to go. If you're making a fairly standard CMS-powered site, Drupal's phenomenal.

Answer (score 15):

[The Onion](http://www.theonion.com/content/index) and [WhiteHouse.gov](http://www.whitehouse.gov/) are Drupal-powered, and I'd say they're fairly huge sites. The founder of the Drupal project keeps [a list](http://buytaert.net/tag/drupal-sites) of some prominent Drupal-powered sites.

Comment: theonion.com switched to Django.

Answer (score 7):

I went to a conference in London a few months back on the subject.  A major UK based charity [Comic Relief](http://www.comicrelief.com/) which has a big TV appeal every 2 years and hit **£80million** ($100 million) in donations this year.  It is run off Drupal, and has a very unique scalability problem in that it only really ets traffic and takes donations on 1 day of the year.

So by using many different database techniques and servers such as reverse proxies it was able to stay working through out the donation day.

It is very possible to make BIG sites on Drupal.

Comment: Very very useful. Thanks! Wish I could mark two posts as the right answer!

Comment: I was probably at the same conference, Comic Relief also ran from EC2, which scaled up to 100s of instances during the appeal day.

Comment: @Jeremy French,  I thought it did use EC2 but wasn't 100%.  There approach to scalability was certainly one we've tried to emulate on a smaller scale.

Answer (score 2):

I've been working with drupal for some time now and it's nice, but have in mind that it does a lot for file scanning/including - 80% time spent on bootstrapping I think I heard some where. But in terms of handling lots of traffic it's performing fine.

Comment: The scanning/including is a big issue for anyone not running an opcode cache like APC. But any large scale site built on PHP will need APC as part of its 'baseline' setup -- it'd be crazy to run a large PHP webapp without it.

Answer (score 2):

i've worked on a very big drupal site and there are serious performance problems, even with two db servers and memcache. the site holds up fine, its just not efficient. most likely its the way we've written everything, but even some very talented drupal guys are scratching their heads. bootstrapping is an issue indeed, as is using amfphp

for something like facebook you need a framework, not something that requires 15 additional modules to set up just a blog ...

Answer (score 2):

Go read the blog of, and listen to the podcasts from, Lullabot - they've been involved with some pretty large sites based on [Drupal](http://www.lullabot.com/).

One large Drupal user I'm aware of (sorry, don't know if it's a Lullabot site or not) is Sony Music - they're using Drupal 6 to roll out sites for their artists. See [Sony Music sponsors major multilingual improvements in Drupal 6](http://drupal.org/node/383954) for more.

Essentially, I believe that the ability of Drupal to scale up will be more than 99% of websites ever need. For the other <1% of sites, there are ways to make things faster.

It's a problem I'd like to have. :-)

Comment: Bingo on the 99%. A site like Facebook, MySpace, Google, etc. is always going to have needs that exceed any existing system - Facebook makes their own patches to memcached, Google has released MySQL patches, etc.

Comment: Yep. We designed and implemented the original Sony BMG platform back in Drupal 5. ;-) They've made the D6 migration, and a number of tweaks they needed have now become an official part of core.